# Android soft keyboard stays open after confirming EditTextPreference dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

Context: I'm working with settings using `PreferenceFragment` and `Activity` (Android 4.4.2 - API 19).

Problem: When clicking "OK" on the resulting dialog from `EditTextPreference`, the soft keyboard stays open.

Attempted Solution: Manually closing the soft keyboard `onSharedPreferenceChanged` inside the fragment. **Only** work if user *changes* and *confirm* the text. **Not** working if the user *cancels*. It also produces another problem namely: When user presses **done**, it *changes* the text, *closes* the keyboard, but leaves the dialog *opened*.

Question: How can I close both the keyboard and dialog when the user *cancels*, *confirm*, or *presses done*, which is a very normal and expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the InputMethodManager.

Comment: That's what I'm doing under the fragment's `onSharedPreferenceChanged`. But the problem with that is if the user clicks "OK" without changing the text or clicks "CANCEL", it won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue. Check if you have
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`
attribute in your `<activity>` tag inside AndroidManifest.xml
Try to remove this string. It helped in my case